# How to stop showing two controls in video player

Tags: javascript, html5-video, video.js

I am using html player to play videos. And then I added **videojs** and **videojs.ima** to show google AdSense. Its working. But there are showing like tow player one is html video player and other is videojs player. Please see attached screenshot.

[image]

My code is:

```
<video class="img-fluid myVideo video-js" id="content_video{{ $video_list->id }}" preload="auto" controls controlsList="nodownload"
    data-video-id="{{ Crypt::encrypt($video_list->id) }}">
    @if (Auth::check())
        @if ($video_list->membershipplan_id == 2 || ($video_list->membershipplan_id == 1 && $video_list->hasPaid == 1) || ($video_list->is_subscription_valid == 1) || ($checkUserSubscriptionPlan == 1))
        <source src="{{ $video_list->full_video_url }}" type="video/mp4" class="full-video">
        @else
        <source src="{{ $video_list->short_video_url }}" type="video/mp4" class="short-video">
        @endif
    @else
        <source src="{{ $video_list->short_video_url }}" type="video/mp4" class="short-video">
    @endif
</video>
```

The above is in loop and there are multiple videos. I am using laravel.

js is:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
console.log('1');
const videos = document.querySelectorAll('.myVideo');
let playing = [];

videos.forEach((video, index) => {
    const overlay = document.querySelectorAll('.overlay')[index];
    const paymentoverlay = document.querySelectorAll('.paymentoverlay')[index];

    // Create a single player instance for each video
    const player = videojs(video.id);

    var options = {
        id: 'content_video',  // Use the correct ID for each video element
        adTagUrl: 'http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?sz=640x480&iu=/124319096/external/ad_rule_samples&ciu_szs=300x250&ad_rule=1&impl=s&gdfp_req=1&env=vp&output=xml_vmap1&unviewed_position_start=1&cust_params=sample_ar%3Dpremidpostpod%26deployment%3Dgmf-js&cmsid=496&vid=short_onecue&correlator='
    };

    player.ima(options);

    video.addEventListener('ended', function() {
        console.log('2');
        // Handle video conditions after it finishes
        handleVideoConditions(video, overlay, paymentoverlay);
    });

    video.onplay = function () {
        console.log('3');
        playing.push(video);
        if (!video.paused) {
            video.controls = true;
            // Trigger an AJAX request to register the view
            registerView(video);
        }
    };
});

function handleVideoConditions(video, overlay, paymentoverlay) {
    console.log('4');
    const isShortVideo = video.querySelector('.short-video');
    const isFullVideo = video.querySelector('.full-video');
    if (!isUserLoggedIn && isShortVideo) {
        console.log('5');
        overlay.style.display = 'block';
    } else if (isUserLoggedIn && isShortVideo) {
        console.log('6');
        paymentoverlay.style.display = 'block';
    }
}    

async function registerView(video) {
    const videoId = video.getAttribute('data-video-id');
    const response = await fetch(`{{ route('video.registerView', ['videoId' => ':videoId']) }}`.replace(':videoId', videoId));
    const data = await response.json();
    $('#videoview'+data.id).html(data.view_count);
}
});
```

Using below css and js:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//googleads.github.io/videojs-ima/node_modules/video.js/dist/video-js.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//googleads.github.io/videojs-ima/node_modules/videojs-contrib-ads/dist/videojs.ads.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//googleads.github.io/videojs-ima/dist/videojs.ima.css" />
<script src="//googleads.github.io/videojs-ima/node_modules/video.js/dist/video.min.js"></script>
<script src="//imasdk.googleapis.com/js/sdkloader/ima3.js"></script>
<script src="//googleads.github.io/videojs-ima/node_modules/videojs-contrib-ads/dist/videojs.ads.min.js"></script>
<script src="//googleads.github.io/videojs-ima/dist/videojs.ima.js"></script>
```

Comment: Try removing the video tag's `controls` attribute, do the other player's controls still appear?

Answer (score 1):

I got my solution and it was so easy. I find class at inspect element and just hide the class.

```
.vjs-has-started .vjs-control-bar {
    display: none;
}
```

Now visible only single player control.